# How can I connect my laptop to the internet for the first time if the network-manger-icon is not displayed?

Tags: internet, icons

I bought a laptop for a friend and installed Ubuntu for him. Since he had no internet connection home when I delivered the laptop I didn't try to build up a connection until now.

I opened the support on the laptop and it gave me the right instruction. Unfortunately it started with: "launch the network-manager".
There should be an icon in the right upper corner, but it is not shown.
I checked if the manager is installed and it is. But I can't access it.

*Sorry for my bad grammar, but I'm not a native English speaker.
This is the first time I deal with Linux and .... I'm quite failing ..... Help...!

Comment: Is there a *Network* panel in System Settings?

Comment: Do you get network access via LAN (i.e. wired / cable connection)?

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu on the computer - now I see the icon but I don't see the network .....

Answer (score 0):

Use a USB Modem. I've always had similar issues, I plug my USB 3G key so that I can update the system and it's all fixed.

Comment: unfotzunately we have no USB Modem